# Counting and displaying count of element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to count and display all the items with span class="check_box cb"(complete) and span class="uncheck_box cb (incomplete) next to complete and incomplete in the [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6CNA2/)

HTML:

```
<span><a href="javascript:;" class="sort active showall">All</a></span>
            <span><a href="javascript:;" class="sort complete">Completed</a></span>
            <span><a href="javascript:;" class="sort incomplete">Incomplete</a></span>

<ul class="leftlist">
<li class="todo" id="1011" itemage="1"><a href="javascript:;"> 
    <a href="javascript:;" class="strike">           
                    <span class="check_box cb"></span>

                <p>Option 1 Complete</p> </a>
</li>

<li class="todo" id="1011" itemage="1"><a href="javascript:;"> 
    <a href="javascript:;">           
                    <span class="uncheck_box cb"></span>

                <p>Option 1 Incomplete</p> </a>
</li>

<li class="todo" id="1011" itemage="1"><a href="javascript:;"> 
    <a href="javascript:;" class="strike">           
                    <span class="check_box cb"></span>

                <p>Option 1 Complete</p> </a>
</li>

<li class="todo" id="1011" itemage="2"><a href="javascript:;"> 
    <a href="javascript:;">          
                    <span class="uncheck_box cb"></span>

                <p>Option 2 InComplete</p> </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/patelmilanb1/6CNA2/2/

```
<div class="complete-count">Complete Count: </div>
<div class="incomplete-count">Incomplete Count:</div>

$('.complete-count').append($('.check_box').length);
$('.incomplete-count').append($('.uncheck_box').length);
```

you can get the length of any elements in DOM using `$(element).length`

**suggestion:** make sure you give a diff classes to elements like for complete `.comple` and for incomplete `.incomple` , what you are doing is correct but your classes are misleading..

Comment: thank..i dont want to show it as an alert but actually display the count. how can i do this?

Comment: thanks.. could it be possible to so that the counter automatically changes the count when an item class is changed without page reload?